# EF Core many to many, cascade delete not working

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a .net core app with EF core 3. I have a many to many relationship with entities VergoedingBedragKm and Verlofgroep. When a VergoedingBedragKm is being deleted, the records in the VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm table which referring to that specific VergoedingBedragKm should be deleted. Following the screenshots of the db below that would mean that when VergoedingBedragKm with id 6 is deleted:
records 5, 10 and 12 in the VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm should be deleted as well, since they contain a reference to the deleted VergoedingBedragKm.

I have 3 db tables:

VergoedingBedragKm:

[image: VergoedingBedragKm]

Verlofgroep:

[image: Verlofgroep]

VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm:

[image: VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm]

snippets of my domain classes:

```
public class Verlofgroep
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Naam { get; private set; }
    public int InstellingId { get; private set; }
    public Instelling Instelling { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm> VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKms { get; private set; }


public class VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm
{
    public int VerlofgroepId { get; private set; }
    public Verlofgroep Verlofgroep { get; private set; }
    public int VergoedingBedragKmId { get; private set; }
    public VergoedingBedragKm VergoedingBedragKm { get; private set; }

public class VergoedingBedragKm
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int InstellingId { get; private set; }
        public Instelling Instelling { get; private set; }
        public TrajectType Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumVanaf { get; set; }
        public ICollection<VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm> VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKms { get; private set; }
        public decimal Bedrag { get; set; }
```

My EF configuration:

```
public class VerlofgroepConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Verlofgroep>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Verlofgroep> builder)
        {
            var table = builder.ToTable("Verlofgroep");
            table.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
        }
    }

public class VergoedingBedragKmConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<VergoedingBedragKm>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VergoedingBedragKm> builder)
        {
            var table = builder.ToTable("VergoedingBedragKm");
            table.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
        }
    }
public class VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKmConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm> builder)
        {
            var table = builder.ToTable("VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm");
            table.HasKey("VerlofgroepId", "VergoedingBedragKmId");
            table.HasOne(vvbk => vvbk.VergoedingBedragKm).WithMany(vbk => vbk.VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKms).HasForeignKey("VergoedingBedragKmId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            table.HasOne(vvbk => vvbk.Verlofgroep).WithMany(vg => vg.VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKms).HasForeignKey("VerlofgroepId");
        }
    }
```

Migrations are done by using FluentMigrator

Migration code of table VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm:

```
Create.Table("VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm")
            .WithColumn("VerlofgroepId").AsInt32().NotNullable().PrimaryKey()
            .WithColumn("VergoedingBedragKmId").AsInt32().NotNullable().PrimaryKey();
```

To implement the cascade delete I've added OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) in the VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKmConfig. But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: The foreign key in the database should also have a cascade clause. If you don't use migrations that may not be the case.

Comment: @GertArnold FluentMigrator is being used. i've added the migration code in the main post. Any idea on where i should place the FK cascade clause?

Comment: I don't know FluentMigrator, but probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941371/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold this was the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding a foreign key with cascade (using Fluentmigrator the code looks like this:)

```
Create.Table("VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm")
            .WithColumn("VerlofgroepId").AsInt32().NotNullable().PrimaryKey()
            .WithColumn("VergoedingBedragKmId").AsInt32().NotNullable().PrimaryKey();

            Create.ForeignKey("FK_VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm_VerlofgroepId_Verlofgroep_Id")
               .FromTable("VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm").ForeignColumn("VerlofgroepId")
               .ToTable("Verlofgroep").PrimaryColumn("Id")
               .OnDeleteOrUpdate(System.Data.Rule.None);

            Create.ForeignKey("FK_VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm_VergoedingBedragKmId_VergoedingBedragKm_Id")
               .FromTable("VerlofgroepVergoedingBedragKm").ForeignColumn("VergoedingBedragKmId")
               .ToTable("VergoedingBedragKm").PrimaryColumn("Id")
               .OnDeleteOrUpdate(System.Data.Rule.Cascade);
```